How to get the upper line of a polygon
I am trying to create an application to automate the workflow of dam analysis for the geotechnical sector I work in. The app takes as input a DXF file that contains the geometry of the dam section. From this file, we extract data such as points, edges, and so on. One of the requirements for the app to work is that the section must be a closed polygon (see images in the example for reference).
Now, I need to find the upper line that "covers" this polygon (the first two images show what this line should be for each example section) and a base line that starts from the leftmost point and goes to the rightmost point. The intention is to have the dam polygon covered by both lines, essentially creating a "sandwich" with these lines to determine its geometry.
I attempted to create this line using my own logic, but it was not successful. I now need a method to find this upper line that covers all points on the top (and only on the top) of the polygon. I searched for algorithms online, but all I could find were algorithms to determine if a point is inside a polygon (such as the convex hull), which do not help me.
Below is the code I have been using to determine this top_line and base_line (which is incorrect). Does anyone know how to solve this or if there are any libraries that could help? I have tried Shapely, but with no success. Thanks in advance, any help is much appreciated!







import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from shapely.geometry import LineString


# Dados das arestas
edges = [
    ((-20.829, 55.53), (-20.829, 53.13)),
    ((-20.829, 55.53), (34.552, 55.53)),
    ((-20.829, 55.53), (-20.829, 58.63)),
    ((-20.829, 53.13), (34.552, 53.13)),
    ((-20.829, 53.13), (-20.829, 49.73)),
    ((34.552, 53.13), (34.552, 55.53)),
    ((34.552, 53.13), (34.552, 49.73)),
    ((34.552, 55.53), (34.552, 57.376)),
    ((-14.727, 59.75), (-18.158, 59.75)),
    ((-14.727, 59.75), (-14.727, 64.737)),
    ((-14.727, 59.75), (-8.625, 59.75)),
    ((-18.158, 59.75), (-18.158, 64.737)),
    ((-18.158, 59.75), (-20.829, 59.75)),
    ((-18.158, 64.737), (-14.727, 64.737)),
    ((-2.25, 64.0), (-8.625, 59.75)),
    ((-2.25, 64.0), (-1.25, 64.0)),
    ((-8.625, 59.75), (-7.625, 59.75)),
    ((-7.625, 59.75), (-1.25, 64.0)),
    ((-7.625, 59.75), (-7.125, 59.75)),
    ((-1.25, 64.0), (-0.75, 64.0)),
    ((-7.125, 59.75), (-0.75, 64.0)),
    ((-7.125, 59.75), (7.125, 59.75)),
    ((-0.75, 64.0), (0.75, 64.0)),
    ((7.125, 59.75), (7.625, 59.75)),
    ((7.125, 59.75), (0.75, 64.0)),
    ((7.625, 59.75), (8.625, 59.75)),
    ((7.625, 59.75), (1.25, 64.0)),
    ((8.625, 59.75), (10.951, 59.75)),
    ((8.625, 59.75), (2.25, 64.0)),
    ((10.951, 59.75), (11.613, 59.487)),
    ((11.613, 59.487), (13.195, 59.11)),
    ((13.195, 59.11), (13.747, 58.75)),
    ((13.747, 58.75), (13.75482973669868, 58.745690645800494)),
    ((13.75482973669868, 58.745690645800494), (13.965006969842744, 58.6300126636222)),
    ((13.75482973669868, 58.745690645800494), (16.755, 58.746)),
    ((13.965006969842744, 58.6300126636222), (-20.829, 58.63)),
    ((13.965006969842744, 58.6300126636222), (15.444, 57.816)),
    ((-20.829, 58.63), (-20.829, 59.75)),
    ((0.75, 64.0), (1.25, 64.0)),
    ((1.25, 64.0), (2.25, 64.0)),
    ((15.586, 57.75), (15.444, 57.816)),
    ((15.586, 57.75), (16.034, 57.516)),
    ((34.552, 57.376), (34.174, 57.271)),
    ((34.174, 57.271), (33.816, 57.194)),
    ((33.816, 57.194), (31.833, 56.75)),
    ((31.833, 56.75), (31.289, 56.716)),
    ((31.289, 56.716), (30.511, 56.695)),
    ((30.511, 56.695), (30.095, 56.693)),
    ((30.095, 56.693), (29.607, 56.699)),
    ((29.607, 56.699), (29.104, 56.718)),
    ((29.104, 56.718), (28.437, 56.75)),
    ((28.437, 56.75), (28.064018072840494, 56.76349934588915)),
    ((28.064018072840494, 56.76349934588915), (27.691, 56.777)),
    ((28.064018072840494, 56.76349934588915), (26.505, 58.652)),
    ((27.691, 56.777), (24.817032481790534, 56.964497880885276)),
    ((24.817032481790534, 56.964497880885276), (21.943, 57.152)),
    ((24.817032481790534, 56.964497880885276), (26.505, 58.652)),
    ((21.943, 57.152), (20.025, 57.067)),
    ((20.025, 57.067), (19.16600997989089, 57.16608651658138)),
    ((19.16600997989089, 57.16608651658138), (17.641, 57.342)),
    ((19.16600997989089, 57.16608651658138), (16.755, 58.746)),
    ((17.641, 57.342), (16.254, 57.447)),
    ((16.254, 57.447), (16.034, 57.516)),
    ((34.552, 37.864), (-20.829, 37.864)),
    ((34.552, 37.864), (34.552, 40.875)),
    ((-20.829, 37.864), (-20.829, 40.875)),
    ((-20.829, 40.875), (34.552, 40.875)),
    ((-20.829, 40.875), (-20.829, 46.59)),
    ((34.552, 40.875), (34.552, 46.59)),
    ((34.552, 46.59), (-20.829, 46.59)),
    ((34.552, 46.59), (34.552, 49.73)),
    ((-20.829, 46.59), (-20.829, 49.73)),
    ((34.552, 49.73), (-20.829, 49.73))
]

# Função para encontrar o ponto mais à esquerda com maior Y
def find_start_point(edges):
    start_point = None
    for edge in edges:
        for point in edge:
            if start_point is None or (point[0] < start_point[0]) or (point[0] == start_point[0] and point[1] > start_point[1]):
                start_point = point
    print("Start Point:", start_point)
    return start_point

def find_end_point(edges):
    end_point = None
    for edge in edges:
        for point in edge:
            if end_point is None or (point[0] > end_point[0]) or (point[0] == end_point[0] and point[1] > end_point[1]):
                end_point = point

    print("End Point:", end_point)
    return end_point


# Função para encontrar o próximo ponto baseado nas arestas conectadas
def find_next_point(current_point, edges, visited_points):
    connected_points = []
    for edge in edges:
        if edge[0] == current_point:
            connected_points.append(edge[1])
        elif edge[1] == current_point:
            connected_points.append(edge[0])

    if not connected_points:
        return None

    # Filtrar os pontos conectados para remover os pontos já visitados
    connected_points = [p for p in connected_points if p not in visited_points]
    if not connected_points:
        return None

    # Verifica se há pontos com Y maior que o do ponto atual
    has_higher_y = any(p[1] > current_point[1] for p in connected_points)
    last_visited_point = visited_points[-2] if len(visited_points) > 1 else current_point

    print("Current Point:", current_point)
    print("Connected Points:", connected_points)
    print("Has Higher Y:", has_higher_y)
    print("Last Visited Point:", last_visited_point)

    if has_higher_y:
        # Priorizar pontos com maior Y e, em caso de empate, menor X
        potential_next_point = max(connected_points, key=lambda p: (p[1], -p[0]))
        print("Potential Next Point (Higher Y):", potential_next_point)
        if potential_next_point[1] > last_visited_point[1]:
            print("Last Visited Point used in comparison", last_visited_point)
            next_point = potential_next_point
        else:
            next_point = max(connected_points, key=lambda p: (p[0], p[1]))
    else:
        # Priorizar pontos com maior Y e maior X
        next_point = max(connected_points, key=lambda p: (p[1], p[0]))

    print("Chosen Next Point:", next_point)
    print("-" * 40)

    return next_point


# Função principal para encontrar a linha de topo
def find_top_line(edges):
    top_line = []
    visited_points = []
    start_point = find_start_point(edges)
    end_point = find_end_point(edges)
    top_line.append(start_point)
    visited_points.append(start_point)  # Adicionar o ponto inicial à lista de pontos visitados
    current_point = start_point

    while True:
        next_point = find_next_point(current_point, edges, visited_points)
        if next_point is None or next_point == start_point or next_point == end_point:
            break
        top_line.append(next_point)
        visited_points.append(next_point)  # Adicionar o próximo ponto aos pontos visitados aqui
        current_point = next_point
        print("Top Line So Far:", top_line)
        print("Visited Points So Far:", visited_points)
        print("=" * 40)

    # Adicionar o ponto final à linha de topo
    if next_point == end_point:
        top_line.append(end_point)

    return top_line


# Função para encontrar o próximo ponto baseado nas arestas conectadas para a linha de fundação
def find_next_point_base(current_point, edges, visited_points):
    connected_points = []
    for edge in edges:
        if edge[0] == current_point:
            connected_points.append(edge[1])
        elif edge[1] == current_point:
            connected_points.append(edge[0])

    if not connected_points:
        return None

    # Se houver mais de um ponto conectado, priorize mover para a direita
    if len(connected_points) > 1:
        connected_points = [p for p in connected_points if p not in visited_points and p[0] > current_point[0]]

    next_point = None
    for point in connected_points:
        if point in visited_points:
            continue
        if next_point is None:
            next_point = point
        elif point[1] < next_point[1]:
            next_point = point
        elif point[1] == next_point[1] and point[0] > next_point[0]:
            next_point = point

    return next_point

# Função principal para encontrar a linha de fundação
def find_base_line(edges):
    base_line = []
    visited_points = set()
    start_point = find_start_point(edges)
    end_point = find_end_point(edges)
    base_line.append(start_point)
    visited_points.add(start_point)
    current_point = start_point

    while True:
        next_point = find_next_point_base(current_point, edges, visited_points)
        if next_point is None or next_point == start_point or next_point == end_point:
            break
        base_line.append(next_point)
        visited_points.add(next_point)
        current_point = next_point

    # Adicionar o ponto final à linha de fundação
    if next_point == end_point:
        base_line.append(end_point)

    return base_line


# Encontrar a linha de topo e a linha de fundação
top_line = find_top_line(edges)

base_line = find_base_line(edges)


# Função para plotar todas as arestas, a linha de topo e a linha de base
def plot_edges_and_lines(edges, top_line, base_line):
    plt.figure(figsize=(10, 8))

    # Plotar todas as arestas
    for edge in edges:
        x_values = [edge[0][0], edge[1][0]]
        y_values = [edge[0][1], edge[1][1]]
        plt.plot(x_values, y_values, 'b-', linewidth=1)

    # Plotar a linha de topo
    top_x = [point[0] for point in top_line]
    top_y = [point[1] for point in top_line]
    plt.plot(top_x, top_y, 'r-', linewidth=2, label='Linha de Topo')

    # Plotar a linha de fundação
    base_x = [point[0] for point in base_line]
    base_y = [point[1] for point in base_line]
    plt.plot(base_x, base_y, 'g-', linewidth=2, label='Linha de Fundação')

    # Configurar o gráfico
    plt.xlabel('X')
    plt.ylabel('Y')
    plt.title('Arestas, Linha de Topo e Linha de Fundação')
    plt.legend()
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.show()

# Plotar todas as arestas e as linhas de topo e fundação
plot_edges_and_lines(edges, top_line, base_line)

I have tried creating my own logic, explicitly specifying which points the line should pass through. This approach worked for the first image in the reference but not for the second. From this, I realized that the logic will vary greatly depending on the polygon.

Looks like you want to compute concave hull, take its outer ring and remove the bottom and side edges.

@yurikilochek That's not correct.

@Sneftel why not?

@yurikilochek The concave hull operation is a heuristic one, which may ignore important features, doesn't consider the line segments, and won't work properly with intersecting boundary segments.

What you're looking for, basically, is a piecewise-defined linear function which, given an X coordinate, returns the maximum intercept among all segments.
There's a number of ways to build this, at varying levels of complexity, optimality, and robustness. The simplest approach -- which isn't that efficient and doesn't properly handle intersecting line segments -- works as follows: Gather the X coordinates of all vertices, and sort them. Ignore all vertical line segments. For each interval between consecutive X coordinates, find the set of segments which overlap that interval, and determine which one has the greatest Y value in the interior of that interval; that part of that segment becomes part of the result. Add vertical line segments between intervals if their endpoints don't match up.
If you need to support intersections in the input, then instead of looking for a single segment for each interval, look for the segment with the greatest Y value immediately to the right of the beginning of the interval. Then look for the first segment (among other segments which are active in that interval) which intersects it within that interval, and clip and transition to that segment; keep going, looking for intersections, until you get to the end of that segment.
The most performant approach is a sweep-line approach, a simple modification of Bentley-Ottmann which, rather than outputting all intersections, outputs only segments and intersections which occur at the top of the active segment list.

Hi @Sneftel, thanks so much for your reply!
I will admit I am still struggling a bit with this alghorithms, so I would really appreaciate you help. I have tried searching for the Bentley-Ottmann alghorithm online, but with no success. Do you know where I can find an implementation of this alghorithm for python, so I can then try to modify it to get only the upper boundary?
Also, I tried using the concave hull, but as you said, it did not work (it had problems when considering lines that had multiple intesections).

Sorry for the double comment, stack overflow limits haha. Anyway, for this segment:
"If you need to support intersections in the input, then instead of looking for a single segment for each interval, look for the segment with the greatest Y value immediately to the right of the beginning of the interval.". I was wondering, even though I might very well be wrong since I am a begginer at coding, what if my section has an edge to the upper left of point I am currently in? I should "retreat" to this point, right? (otherwise I would let this point open, I assume). Again, thank you!!
